# Parse an HTML elements tree to a nested parentheses symbolic expression in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Put simply, how to go from an HTML element with some other elements nested like this:

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="obj">1</div>
    <div class="obj">2</div>
    <div class="obj">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="obj">a</div>
    <div class="obj">b</div>
    <div class="obj">c</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To a string like this:

```
((1 2 3) (a b c))
```

Using jQuery?

Comment: Google "XML parser".

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```js
var string = '(' + $('.box .box').map(function() { 
        return '(' + $(this).find('.obj').map(function() { return $(this).text(); }).get().join(' ') + ')';
    }).get().join(' ') + ')';

alert(string);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="obj">1</div>
    <div class="obj">2</div>
    <div class="obj">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="obj">a</div>
    <div class="obj">b</div>
    <div class="obj">c</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Output: `((1 2 3) (a b c))`

Answer (score 0):

You can read out all items with a each function.
In the variable text you will have the single text from each element with the class .obj.

```
    var string = "";
    $(".box").each(function(){
       $(".obj").each(function(){
          var text = $(this).text();
          string += text;
       });
    });
```

In the each function you also can format the variables as you like it.